# Use custom classes in Magento 2 controller

Tags: magento2, php, cms, class

I'm migrating my module from Magento 1 to Magento 2, some code is no longer working.

Instantiating the class doesn't work anymore, is there a different way to do it in Magento 2?

```
include("pathtomyclass");
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

public function execute() {


    $this->_view->loadLayout();
     $this->_setActiveMenu(
        'company_project::themenuitem'
    );
    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(Title of my module'));
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
    $class = new myClass();
```

This doesn't work as it says cannot redclare myClass.

I tried to replace the last line with this one

```
$class = $this->_objectManager->create('company\project\Model\myClass');
```

It gives the same error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What type of class you have tried. It's custom library or Inside your module

Comment: @SohelRana inside my module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove following line

```
include("pathtomyclass");
```

Now you can use your custom class following way:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Company\Project\Model\MyClass
     */
    protected $myClass;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
     * @param \Company\Project\Model\MyClass $myClass
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Company\Project\Model\MyClass $myClass
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->myClass = $myClass;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

Inside your controller you can access following way:

```
$this->myClass->MyMethod()
```

Comment: I get the following error:Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Company\Project\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\magento8\var\generation\Company\Project\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\index\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in C:\wamp\www\magento8\app\code\Company\Project\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\index.php on line 32

Comment: Remove var/generation/* , Clear cache.

Comment: so after cleaning cache I got another error: Class Company\Project\Model\MyClass does not exist

Comment: Create a class following location: Company\Project\Model\MyClass.php

Comment: its there already, and I could access it when included, thanks for your support, really appreciated

Comment: Could you post your MyClass.php?

Comment: class MyClass {
 public function __construct() {
  return "This is a test!";
    }
 
}

Comment: Could you add 'namespace Company\Project\Model', start of your class. Also see updated answer. Folder name must be Upper case first.

Comment: I still have some issues as I cant instantiate my classes or interfaces from within MyClass, I use include_once but I get an error that says cannot redeclare class, do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Don't use include, include_once, require, require_once. Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php and http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Thanks .. I had no idea how to use namespaces